# How do i change the state of another button onPress onReact Native?

Tags: javascript, function, react-native, react-hooks, expo

I have 2 buttons which if pressed, change their background color. If i press both, they both change background color. I'd like to switch background color between the two (e.g. if i press one, the other one goes back to original state) How can i achieve that? `

```
const [color, setColor] = useState("false");
const [font, setFont] = useState("#505050");
const [color2, setColor2] = useState(false);
const [font2, setFont2] = useState("#505050");

function onClick() {
    const colors = [
      "#ff6700",
      "#ffffff"
    ]

if ( colors.indexOf(color) === 0 ) {
    setColor(colors[1]); 
} else {
    setColor(colors[0]); 
}

const fonts = [
  "#ffffff",
  "#505050"
]
if ( fonts.indexOf(font) === 0 ) {
    setFont(fonts[1]); 
} else {
    setFont(fonts[0]); 
}
}

function onClick2() {
    const colors2 = [
      "#ff6700",
      "#ffffff"
    ]

if ( colors2.indexOf(color2) === 0 ) {
    setColor2(colors2[1]); 
} else {
    setColor2(colors2[0]); 
}

const fonts2 = [
  "#ffffff",
  "#505050"
]
if ( fonts2.indexOf(font2) === 0 ) {
    setFont2(fonts2[1]); 
} else {
    setFont2(fonts2[0]); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Should they both always change their color or only if one of the buttons has the "active" color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically need conditional logic to check whether the other button is active. You can do it like this:

```
  const App = props => {
      const [color, setColor] = React.useState(false);
      const [color2, setColor2] = React.useState(false);

      const toggle = function () {
        if (color) {
          setColor(false);
        } else {
          setColor(true);
          setColor2(false);
        }
      };

      const toggle2 = function () {
        if (color2) {
          setColor2(false);
        } else {
          setColor2(true);
          setColor(false);
        }
      };

      return (
        <div>
          <button
            style={{ backgroundColor: color ? "#ff6700" : "#ffffff" }}
            onClick={toggle}
          >
            Button1
          </button>
          <button
            onClick={toggle2}
            style={{ backgroundColor: color2 ? "#ff6700" : "#ffffff" }}
          >
            Button2
          </button>
        </div>
      );
    };
```

Here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/Gh05d/pen/xxwoEXg?editors=1111) for you to try it out.

Comment: Happy to help :-)

Comment: how can i also change font color dynamically?

Comment: Basically the same principle as with the color. Update the toggle functions with your setState method for the font color and in the style prop add another check for font-color. They should work exact the same way as the color functionality, so you only have to copy the logic.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps you. If not, let me know.

My solution is quite messy and not really good code. I hope it can give you some idea. A different idea is you can use `useRef` to mark the current ref of the button's color. From there setState conditionally based on those refs

Also you should check your code again. You should use `useState(false)` not `"false"`

```
const [color, setColor] = useState(null);
const [color2, setColor2] = useState(null);


const onClick = (button) => {

    if(button == 1){
        if(color2 == "changed color"){
            setColor("color 1");
            setColor2("origin color");
        }else{
            setColor("color 1");
        }
    }else{
        if(color1 == "changed color"){
            setColor2("color 2");
            setColor("origin color");
        }else{
            setColor2("color 2");
        }
    }


}
```

Then pass it like this:

```
<button onClick={() => onClick(1)}>Button 1</button>
<button onClick={() => onClick(2)}>Button 2</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood, you want to change the colors of both buttons upon clicking just one. One way to do it could be:

```
<button onClick={() => {onClick1(); onClick2();}}>Button 1</button>
<button onClick={() => {onClick1(); onClick2();}}>Button 2</button>
```

Or you could even call the other function in the function itself. Like:

```
function onClick1() {
    ...
    onClick2();
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. However, what i'm trying to achieve is to only change background color one button at time and not have both changed at the same time. For example, if i tap on button 1, it changes background. Now, if i also tap on button 2, i'd like the button 1 to go back to first background and the button 2 to change background. I don't want to have both buttons showing both changed background at once.

Comment: You can use setColor1(false) in the function onClick2()? So whenever that runs, it ensures that the first button color is reset.

Comment: thanks. How can i exactly implement that? Sorry, i'm a beginner.